# ¿Cómo cargar un template (plantilla) usando EPPLUS en asp.net?

Tags: php, asp.net, vb.net, asp, basic

**Un saludo para todos,**

estoy intentando cargar una plantilla excel, usando la librería EPPLUS; para luego, agregarle la data en celdas específicas; sin embargo, no logro cargar la plantilla.

**NOTA: Estoy utilizando ASP.NET (2.0) con Visual Basic** ****(ES URGENTE)****

```
Dim path As String
Dim pathAux As FileInfo     
Dim excelPackage As ExcelPackage
Dim workSheet As ExcelWorksheet
Dim file As FileInfo

    path = rutaAbsoluta & "\excel\plantilla.xls"

    file = New FileInfo(path)

    If file.Exists Then
        file.Delete()
        file = New FileInfo(path)
    End If

    pathAux = New FileInfo(path)
    excelPackage = New ExcelPackage(file, pathAux)
```

**Gracias a todos por sus comentarios.**

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

**Estimados, gracias por sus respuestas**

le he dado permisos a los archivos y a la carpeta; ahora ya me permite generar el archivo excel "nuevoArchivo.xls"; sin embargo, obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error al intentar abrir el archivo excel: "nuevoArchivo.xls" luego de realizar una prueba con el archivo excel que utilizo como plantilla: "archivoplantilla.xls", recalco nuevamente que requiero trabajar sobre una plantilla de excel que ya tiene una estructura; sólo requiero agregar la data en las celdas correspondientes. (Lineas abajo, presento el código que he utilizado). Tal vez esté un poco confundido en cómo funciona excelPackage, en el uso de plantillas)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
        Dim rutaNuevoArchivo As String
        Dim fileNuevoArchivo As FileInfo
        Dim rutaArchivoPlantilla As String
        Dim fileArchivoPlantilla As FileInfo

        rutaNuevoArchivo = rutaAbsoluta & "\excel\nuevoArchivo.xls"

        fileNuevoArchivo = New FileInfo(rutaNuevoArchivo)

        If fileNuevoArchivo.Exists Then
            fileNuevoArchivo.Delete()
            fileNuevoArchivo = New FileInfo(rutaNuevoArchivo)
        End If

        rutaArchivoPlantilla = rutaAbsoluta & "\excel\archivoplantilla.xls"
        fileArchivoPlantilla = New FileInfo(rutaArchivoPlantilla)
        
        **excelPackage = New ExcelPackage(fileNuevoArchivo, fileArchivoPlantilla)**

        workSheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Formato")

        workSheet.Cells(11, 3).Value = "JOSE CABANILLAS"
        workSheet.Cells(12, 3).Value = "MARIA JOSE"
        workSheet.Cells(13, 3).Value = "ODONTOLOGIA CHICLAYO"
        workSheet.Cells(14, 3).Value = "123456"
        workSheet.Cells(16, 3).Value = "03/04/2021"
        workSheet.Cells(18, 3).Value = "  PRESTAMO (  )          CUSTODIA ( X )          REPARACION (  )               OTRO (  )"


      
        excelPackage.Save()
```

**Espero puedan orientarme, Muchas Gracias.**

Answer (score 0):

**Estimados muchas gracias a todos por su aporte**; finalmente he podido superar el problema,
líneas abajo dejo el fragmento de código esencial, que me permitió cargar una plantilla en formato excel (.xlsx) y agregarle data; usando la librería EPPLUS, en ASP.NET y Visual Basic.

***Importante:*** El archivo excel debe estar necesariamente en formato (.xlsx) y se debe agregar los permisos necesarios a dicho archivo excel, si utiliza el IIS  debe agregarle permisos al usuario del aplicativo IIS en el archivo excel.

```
        Dim rutaArchivo As String = ""
        Dim excelPackage As ExcelPackage
        Dim workSheet As ExcelWorksheet


        Dim rutaArchivoPlantilla As String
        Dim fileArchivoPlantilla As FileInfo
         
        rutaArchivoPlantilla = rutaAbsoluta & "\excel\formatoExcelPlantilla.xlsx"
        fileArchivoPlantilla = New FileInfo(rutaArchivoPlantilla)

        excelPackage = New ExcelPackage(fileArchivoPlantilla)

        workSheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets(1)

        workSheet.Cells(11, 3).Value = "JOSE PEEZ"
        workSheet.Cells(12, 3).Value = "ALEX GONZALES"
        workSheet.Cells(13, 3).Value = "ODONTOLOGIA CHICLAYO"
        workSheet.Cells(14, 3).Value = "123456"
        workSheet.Cells(16, 3).Value = "03/04/2021"
        workSheet.Cells(18, 3).Value = "PRESTAMO"

        excelPackage.Save()
```

**Espero pueda ayudar este fragmento de código a alguien más. Muchas Gracias.**